# TensorImage cannot load bitmap

Tags: android, image, android-studio, tensorflow, kotlin

I'm trying to use `TensorImage.load()` to load a bitmap of picture the user took with the camera app. When I pass in the bitmap I get this error:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Only supports loading ARGB_8888 bitmaps`

This is my code for when I call the `load` function. First, it starts with the `onActivityResult`:

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 28) {
            val foodBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.contentResolver, Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
            // pass this bitmap to the classifier
            val predictions = foodClassifier.recognizeImage(foodBitmap, 0)
        } else {
            val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(this.contentResolver, Uri.fromFile(photoFile))
            val foodBitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
            // pass this bitmap to the classifier
            val predictions = foodClassifier.recognizeImage(foodBitmap, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

In the `recognizeImage` function, I call a variable named `inputImageBuffer` which is of type `TensorImage`. I call the `load` function and pass the `bitmap`. This is where the application crashes. Can someone tell me how do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I solved the issue by changing the bitmap configuration in simplest way.

Bitmap bmp =  imageBitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888,true) ;

Here
ii - Bitmap is immutable therefore I have make a copy with Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888 configuration and a new Bitmap with refrence,
for further reference
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else this is how I solved the issue by changing the bitmap configuration.

```
// Convert the image to a Bitmap
        var bitmap: Bitmap? = null
        try {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                val source = ImageDecoder.createSource(requireContext().contentResolver, uri!!)
                bitmap = ImageDecoder.decodeBitmap(source)
                bitmap = bitmap.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)
            } else {
                bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(requireContext().contentResolver, uri!!)
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Could not convert image to BitMap")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
```